# Showing the function by $F(t) = \int_{(-\infty,t]} f(x)dx$. is continuous, uniformly bounded, etc

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ and for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ define the function $F$ by $F(t) = \int_{(-\infty,t]} f(x)dx$. Prove that $F$ is continuous, uniformly bounded and that:

$lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} F(t) = 0$

and that

$lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} F(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}fdx$

---

So this result makes a lot of sense. Since $f$ is integrable $F$ should converge to the $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$, and converge to $0$ as $t \rightarrow -\infty$.

So, I can easily show that, $F$ is uniformly bounded by the value of $\int_\mathbb{R} f$. Can somebody help me to show that $F$ is continuous? Rigorous details appreciated!

The convergences as $t$ goes to $-\infty,\infty$ also make sense, but I was hoping somebody could give me insight as to how to prove it!! Again, rigorous details appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: for all the convergence things and continuity apply the monotone convergence theorem or the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT

Use sequential characterization of limits.

Let $t_n \to +\infty$

Denote  $f_n=f(x)1_{(-\infty,t_n]}$

Then $f_n \to f(x)$ and by Dominated convergence you have the conclusion.

Do the same for an arbitrary sequence $y_n \to -\infty$

Comment: Any tips for showing uniform boundedness and continuity? I feel like uniform boundedness Is tricky because the $F$ doesn't necessarily need to be increasing..

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom the uniform bound is $\int |f|$